# How to retrieve previously enter data in a form in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have written code to display a form on the html page in django. When I click on the update button, everytime, it is showing an empty form. But what I want is, if I have entered some data previously, that data should be displayed in the form normally. Then I have to be able to edit it. But, I am getting an empty form everytime.

views.py:

```
def update_longterm(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'cups4/index.html')
else:
    form = LongtermForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        longterm = form.save(commit=False)
        longterm.user = request.user
        longterm.body = form.cleaned_data['body']
        longterm.save()
        return render(request, 'cups4/detail_longterm.html', {'longterm': longterm})
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'cups4/create_template.html', context)
```

Models.py:

```
class NotNecessary(models.Model):
title = models.TextField("NotNecessary",editable=False)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                        unique_for_date='publish')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField()
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Forms.py:

```
class LongtermForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Longterm
    fields = [ 'body',]
```

template:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Immediate{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Immediate Goals</h3>
                    {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% include 'cups4/form_template.html' %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Everytime, a new form is displayed. Instead, I want the previous data to be loaded. How to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There may be two situations:

1. When you are updating already created object, then you may fetch it from the database and pass as: `form = LongtermForm(instance=your_object)`
2. In other case, if your are adding a new object and you want to see the previously entered information by the user in case of some errors. You may render form as:

   `form = LongtermForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)`

In both the cases please make sure you are rendering **form.errors** and **form.non_field_errors** in case if you are manually rendering your form in *create_template.html*, otherwise django will take care of it automatically , if you render it like , for eg. `{{ form.as_p }}`